# Count how many dates in a list are between two dates

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the given schema

```
(t1:Tag)-[c:CONNECTED_TO]-(t2:Tag)
```

Each relationship of type :CONNECTED_TO has a property that is storing dates as a list.

```
{
  "dates": [
    "2019-11-27",
    "2019-01-24",
    "2017-06-27"
  ]
}
```

Now I want to find each relationship where one of the dates is between two dates.

```
MATCH ()-[c:CONNECTED_TO]-()
WHERE ANY (item IN c.dates WHERE date({year: 2019, month: 12}) > item >= date({year: 2019, month: 10}))
RETURN c
```

But in addition, I also want to count how many dates in the list-property are between those two dates. For the above example, it should return 1 because only one date on the list is between 2019-12-01 and 2019-10-01.

How can I do that?

**Edit**

I found the following solution for my problem:

```
MATCH ()-[c:CONNECTED_TO]-()
WITH [x IN range(0,size(c.dates)-1) WHERE date({year: 2019, month: 12}) > c.dates[x] >= date({year: 2019, month: 1})] AS index, id(c) AS id
RETURN id, size(index) AS Size
```

Sadly this solution is very slow. The date-list can be of size 10.000 or higher. If there is somebody with a faster solution I would be happy to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your `MATCH` is scanning ALL the nodes in your database to find the `CONNECTED_TO` relationships. You should be qualifying the end nodes with the `Tag` label to scan just the `Tag` nodes.
2. You should be calculating the static `date` values just once.
3. You should use the `REDUCE` function instead of list comprehension (which generates new lists that your query will just drop) to count the dates within range.
4. There is no need to use the `RANGE` function, which also generates a list.

This query should be faster:

```
WITH date({year: 2019, month: 12}) AS a, date({year: 2019, month: 1}) AS b
MATCH (:Tag)-[c:CONNECTED_TO]-(:Tag)
RETURN ID(c) AS id, REDUCE(s=0, d IN c.dates | CASE WHEN a > d >= b THEN s + 1 ELSE s END) AS Size
```

Comment: This query reduces the completion time from 600s to 600ms. Awesome help. Thank you a lot.